# How pass parameters to a dynamic function after a Windows process exits?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dynamic, process

I want to start a Process and not wait for its completion.
However, when the process exits, I'd like to call another Process and pass parameters to it.

I can do this with a *known* function like this:

```
public static void RunCommand(string path, string parms, string completion)
{
    Process myProc = new Process();

    myProc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    myProc.StartInfo.Arguments = parms;
    myProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    myProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProc.Exited += (sender, ex) => CommandExecuted(sender, ex, completion);
    myProc.Start();
}

private static void CommandExecuted(object sender, System.EventArgs e, string completion)
{
    //do stuff with "completion" string
}
```

What I'd like to do is pass another function in at run time rather than the known function `CommandExecuted`.

How do I pass a reference to a function and include the parameters for that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional `Action` parameter to your method - an Action is a variable that represents a method with no return type. So if you change your declaration to:

```
public static void RunCommand(string path, string parms, string completion, 
    Action<object, EventArgs, string> exitedCallback)
{
    Process myProc = new Process();

    myProc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    myProc.StartInfo.Arguments = parms;
    myProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    myProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProc.Exited += (o, e) => exitedCallback(o, e, completion);
    myProc.Start();
}
```

So now, even at runtime, you can pass any method that matches the signature:

```
RunCommand("1.exe", string.Empty, string.Empty, CommandExecuted);
RunCommand("1.exe", string.Empty, string.Empty, (o, e, c) => Console.WriteLine("Foo"));
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation using a method delegate, in case the delegate needs to return something when it processes the `completion` string.
I've added the `EventArgs` parameter, since it's in your question, but I don't see how this can be useful. You could ignore it here.

You could also do this without a **`delegate`** declaration and just pass:

```
Func<object, EventArgs, string, string> completionFunc
```

instead of the `CompletionFunc completionFunc` parameter in the `RunCommand` method.

---

```
public delegate string CompletionFunc(object o, EventArgs e, string s);

public static void RunCommand(string path, string parms, string completion, CompletionFunc completionFunc)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    Process myProc = new Process();

    myProc.StartInfo.FileName = path;
    myProc.StartInfo.Arguments = parms;
    myProc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    myProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProc.Exited += (obj, evt) => {
        result = completionFunc(obj, evt, completion);
        Console.WriteLine($"{result} ExitCode: {myProc.ExitCode})");
        if (myProc != null) myProc.Dispose();
    };
    myProc.Start();
}
```

Calling the `RunCommand` method.
As a test, I'm using `tracert.exe` to trace an IP address (it takes a while to complete).
The `RunCommand` method is executed asynchronously and will print to the Console its results when the `Exited` event is raised.

The `str` parameter, here, will be the `completion` string value when the `RunCommand` method executes.

This allows three different method calls:

**In-lined**:

```
string completion = "[Some Data]";

RunCommand("tracert.exe", "[Some IP Address]", completion, (obj, evt, str) => {
    return $"Completion: {str + " : Completed"} " +
           $"Process: {((Process)obj).StartInfo.FileName} " +
           $"Result: {"Some result"}";
});
```

**Using a Local Function**:

```
private void SomeStartingMethod()
{
    string MethodCall(object obj, EventArgs evt, string str)
    {
        return $"Completion: {str + " : Completed"} " +
               $"Process: {((Process)obj).StartInfo.FileName} " +
               $"Result: {"Some result"}";
    }

    string completion = "[Some Data]";
    RunCommand("tracert.exe", "[Some IP Address]", completion, MethodCall);
}
```

**Using a method that matches the delegate signature**:

```
string MethodCall2(object obj, EventArgs evt, string str)
{
    return $"Completion: {str + " : Completed"} " +
           $"Process: {((Process)obj).StartInfo.FileName} " +
           $"Result: {"Some result"}";
}


// Somewhere else
string completion = "[Some Data]";
RunCommand("tracert.exe", "[Some IP Address]", completion, MethodCall2);
```

These all will print:

```
Completion: [Some Data] : Completed Process: tracert.exe Result: Some result ExitCode: 0)
```

Comment: Very interesting... I'll give all these a go and see how they work!  Much Appreciated!

Comment: The first answer did answer my original question but Jimi, you gave me some really good information and probably will need in the future.  These answers should provide great help for anyone looking to do something like this!